# Finding a general term in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I have two variable polynomials given by:

$$ a^{l,n}_{m}(X,Y) = \underset{k_1+k_2=l+n}{\sum_{k_1=-m}^{l+n} \sum_{k_2 = m}^{l -n +2m}} X^{k_1}Y^{k_2}
= \sum_{k=0}^{l - n + m} X^{l + n - m - k} Y^{k + m}.$$

I was able to write this formula looking at the table representation:
[image]

I would also like to write the similar formula for next table: 
[image]

In this case, I was able to figure out the case when $n=0$;

$$ a^{l,0}_{m}(X,Y) = \underset{k_1+k_2=l}{\sum_{k_1=0}^{l+m-1} \sum_{k_2 = 1}^{l+m+1}} X^{k_1}Y^{k_2}. $$
But I failed when trying to get the general case. How can I figure this out?

P.S. I can generate more terms in tables to check if results are correct.

Comment: Could you compute higher $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the figures for one row and column.

Comment: It is frustrating because of the well known polynoms involve in.

Comment: Yet, you can note that with $n$ bigger here 3 , the $X$ disappears for $m=3$ ans is almost beautiful before you see $X$ power increasing by two on the diag.

Comment: Think we can find this.

Comment: What got me worried in the second table, is that the number of terms in brackets do not grow with $m$ but start dropping, which is different than in the first table. I suspect this was the reason I failed and might be pointing out that my ansatz function is just too simple.

Comment: I think you can"t do better than redexing with only $k_1$

Comment: So I had something like this initially for the formulas I wrote above (I added it now to the post for the first case), but eventually thought it would be easier to generalize to the second case if I have two sums instead of one.

Comment: I understood , second table is kind of pathologic